user deleted on component change
when i change path the user is deleted and auth doesnt work. When i go to another component user == undefined. How to set the user after login for the whole project until logOut?
export class AuthService implements OnDestroy {
  private user$$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);
  public user$ = this.user$$.asObservable();
  private unsubscribe!: Unsubscribe;
  subscription: Subscription;


  isEditMode: boolean = false;
  user: User | undefined;

  USER_KEY = '[user]';



  get isLogged(): boolean { 
    return   this.user$$.value !== undefined;
  }

  constructor(private afa: AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.subscription = this.user$.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
  

  signUp(email: string, password: string, mobile: string) {
    const db = getFirestore();

    const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
    const q = query(usersRef, where("phoneNumber", "==", mobile));

    return getDocs(q).then(async (querySnapshot) => {
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        // Phone number already registered

        throw new Error("This phone number is already registered.");
      } else {
        this.afa.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(async params => {
          const uid = params.user?.uid


          await setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid!), {
            phoneNumber: mobile
          }).catch(
            (error) => {
              throw error;
            }
          );
        }).catch(
          (error) => {
            throw error;
          }
        );
      }
    })

  };






  loginUser = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      // Signed in
      const user = userCredential.user;

      // You can store user info in your application state or context
      this.user$$.next(user);
      this.unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {

          console.log("User  is signed in:");
          this.user$$.next(user);
          // Update the BehaviorSubject with the user
        } else {
          console.log("No user is signed in.");
          this.user$$.next(undefined); // Clear the user
        }
      });
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));


      return user; // Return user for further use if needed
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error logging in:", error);
      throw error; // Handle the error as needed
    }
  };


  signOut() {
    this.afa.signOut().then(() => {
      this.user$$.next(undefined);
      localStorage.clear();
    });
  }


  getProfile() {
    return this.user$$.value;
  }

  async getUserDetails() {
    const user = this.user$$.value;
    const uid = user.uid;
    const db = getFirestore();
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", uid);

    let phoneNumber = "";
    let address = "";

    await getDoc(docRef).then((snapshot) => {
      const userData = snapshot.data();
      const userPhoneNumber = userData?.['phoneNumber'];
      const userAddress = userData?.['address'];
      phoneNumber = userPhoneNumber;
      address = userAddress;
     
    })
    return { phoneNumber, address };

  }


  async updateProfile(user: any) {
    if (user.email) {
      const auth = getAuth();
      updateEmail(auth.currentUser!, user.email).then(() => {
        window.alert("Email changed!")
      }).catch((error) => {
        throw new Error(error)
      });
    }

    if (user.phoneNumber || user.address) {
      const currentUser = this.user$$.value;
      const uid = currentUser.uid;

      const db = getFirestore();
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid);

      if (user.phoneNumber) {
        await updateDoc(userRef, {
          phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
        }).then(() => {
          window.alert("Phone number updated!")
        })
      }

      if (user.address) {
        await updateDoc(userRef, {
          address: user.address,
        }).then(() => {
          window.alert("Shipping address updated!")
        })
      }

    }

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    
    
    this.user$$.next(undefined); // Clear the user
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  
  }
}



is authService providedIn: root please add the service with the decorator, how are you performing the navigation, are you using routerlink, do you have authService in any providers array of modules or components?

The problem was that i forgot to type routerlink = "" and it was herf="". Thank you for the comment, i was searching for the problem like 4  hours :D.
